# Completion of setValue() causes crash Firebase, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I am currently updating an App to Swift 3 and iOS 10. The Problem is whenever I use:

```
    self.ref.setValue(value, withCompletionBlock: { (error: Error?, _:FIRDatabaseReference) in
            //Code
        })
```

The App crashes without any kind of information on why it does that. If I delete the completion, it works fine.

Comment: Make sure your `ref` is not nil, most probably is.

Comment: @Dravidian Should I check that in the completion or before?

Comment: Try printing before....

Comment: @Dravidian its not nil

Comment: Are you running it on simulator or on device? And what about the value , try printing that.Also try replacing `(error: Error?, _:FIRDatabaseReference)` to `(err, snapRef)`

Comment: @Dravidian I am running on an device and its not working

Comment: @M.Kremer i'm also having same issue will you please help me have you got answer for that. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, i hope this will do the trick

```
// U can use this to set value to your database
func setValue() {
    let myRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Your path")
    let valueForChild: String = "newValue"
    let newValue = ["childName": valueForChild] as [String: Any]
    myRef.setValue(newValue) { (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to update value")
        } else {
            print("Success update newValue to database")
        }
    }
}

// or this to update new value to your database
func updateValue() {
    let myRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Your path")
    let valueForChild: String = "newValue"
    let newValue = ["childName": valueForChild] as [String: Any]
    myRef.updateChildValues(newValue) { (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription, "Failed to update value")
        } else {
            print("Success update newValue to database")
        }
    }
}
```